# Dynamically update BxSlider when adding new images with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bxslider

I am using [BxSlider](http://www.bxslider.com) jQuery to display a number of images in a slider. I load the images in an unordered list and they are displayed in the slider. All good so far.

Ok so here is the issue I am trying to solve. I have a lot of pictures and I want to load only the first 40 for starters. When the slider reaches the last one, I am planning on adding new ones through an Ajax request.

The option to reload the slider to take the new images is by using the following methods.

- [`reloadSlider()`](http://bxslider.com/examples/reload-slider)
- `destroySlider()`

But what it does it reloads the slider and starts again with the first image, while what I want is to continue the slide with the added images.

Any suggestions/help in regards to this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: I was just thinking of maybe remembering the index of the last image somehow and rewrite the reloadSlider to start from that index? Not sure if possible...
By the way, I am quite new to jQuery/Ajax stuff :)

Answer (score 4):

It may be too late for you, but not for others, bxSlider API allows you to get the current slide with

```
yourSlider.getCurrentSlide()
```

This way you can store your current slide index somewhere and use it again when you reload your slider with

```
yourSlider.reloadSlider()
```

using the option `startSlide`

This would go about this way:

```
var mySlider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();

/* The part where you add your images */

var currentSlide = mySlider.getCurrentSlide();

mySlider.reloadSlider({
    startSlide: currentSlide,
    //whatever your options were
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Just noticed the answer. Will give it a go soon and will let you know how it goes. Cheers.

Comment: @BogdanGoie I need similar feature on my site. Can you share the the code to load images via AJAX or the full code for this?